# Finding the use of the word 'Cthulhu' in tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: sql, stackexchange

I've written the following SQL to count the number of times the name 'Cthulhu' turns up for each tag on Stack Overflow (original [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1527/cthulhu-fhtagn)):

```
select t.TagName, count (*) 'Tainted'
from Posts p, Tags t, PostTags pt
where p.Body like '%cthulhu%'
and (pt.PostId = p.Id and t.Id = pt.TagId)
group by t.TagName
order by Tainted DESC, t.TagName ASC
```

It works, but I'm not used to cutting SQL manually; I'm more accustomed to using ORMs.  I tried using `CONTAINS` instead of `LIKE`, but apparently `Body` isn't set up for full-text search.

Could you please provide me some feedback - in particular, are there any best practices I'm missing, and whether there are standard formatting rules for SQL that would make it a bit easier on the eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t.TagName, count (*) 'Tainted'
  from Posts p
 inner join PostTags pt on (pt.PostId == p.Id)
 inner join Tags t on (t.Id == pt.TagId)
 where lower(p.Body) like '%cthulhu%'
 group by t.TagName
 order by Tainted desc, t.TagName asc
```

- Notice the `lower` on the body, because `like` is (should?) be case sensitive.
- The joins are also easier to read IMHO than the conditions in the where clause.
- The formatting is based on right-aligning keywords and left-aligning clauses.

Comment: Like *is* case sensitive. Formatting suggestion...capitalize the SQL keywords? You have ASC and DESC caps, but otherwise all lower case.

Comment: @Michael K.: Thanks for your notes. I said that `like` "should" be case sensitive just to be on the safe side (in case a DBMS such as SQL Server or MySQL has an option to make it insensitive). I didn't notice the casing of the words `ASC` and `DESC` when I copied them. I have corrected them; thanks.

Comment: As for capitalization, I prefer to use small letters as long as I have syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Hosam Consistency trumps preference for me. I care less about the style than whether it's applied universally :) Good point about other DBMS's.

Comment: @Michael K: Isn't it case-sensitive simply because the collation for `p.Body` is case-sensitive? Because this simple test shows that generally speaking, LIKE is *not* case-sensitive: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'A' UNION ALL SELECT 'sad' UNION ALL SELECT 'good-bye') x (f) WHERE f LIKE '%A%'`. This returns two rows on my computer (SQL Server 2008 R2) as well as in SE Data Explorer (don't know what server they use).

Comment: @Andriy: It sounds like it isn't case sensitive by default on SQL Server then. I know it is on DB2, and it looks like [Oracle has a setting](http://www.orafaq.com/node/91) for it. A quick search didn't reveal anything either way about MySQL.